# snowflake number convertion based on digits and find the list of numbers between the range

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Trying to standardize column b numbers and find the numbers between them

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 34 |
| 113 | 17 |
| 308 | 12 |

need to change column b based on the column a  and list of numbers between them.

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnBupdated | numberlist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 34 | 34 | [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34] |
| 113 | 17 | 117 | [113,114,115,116,117] |
| 308 | 12 | 312 | [308,309,310,311,312] |

```
select (case when length(column_A) <> length(column_b) and column_b is not null and column_b <>'' and to_number(column_A % 2) = 0  then TO_NUMBER(column_A) + TO_NUMBER(column_b) when length(column_A) <> length(column_b) and column_b is not null and column_b <>'' and to_number(column_A % 2) = 1  then TO_NUMBER(column_A) + TO_NUMBER(column_b) -1 else column_b end) as column_b_Clean from table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

So using the [LPAD()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html) we can resolve the first problem of getting ColumnBUpdated sorted.

Next we can use [REPEAT()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/repeat.html) to get a nice list of numbers between ColumnA and the ColumnBUpdated.

Then we just slap it into an array using [ARRAY_AGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) using the INDEX variable that comes free from our [Lateral](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) [Flatten()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) and Bob's your uncle!

```
with cte as( 
       select 20 ColumnA, 34 ColumnB
union all select 113 ColumnA, 17 ColumnB
union all select 308 ColumnA, 12 ColumnB) 
, cte2 as (select ColumnA,ColumnB,LPAD(ColumnB,length(ColumnA),ColumnA) ColumnBUpdated,ColumnBUpdated-ColumnA Q  from cte) 

SELECT 
    ColumnA
,   ColumnB
,   ColumnBUpdated
,   ARRAY_AGG(COLUMNA+INDEX)   
FROM 
    cte2 
    , LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(REPEAT('hire me $3/hour',Q),'hire me $3/hour') 
GROUP BY 
    1,2,3 ;
```

An alternative solution:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA
,   ColumnB
,   ColumnBUpdated
,   ARRAY_AGG(COLUMNA+INDEX)   
FROM  
     CTE2 
    ,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=>STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(REPEAT('1~',Q),'~') ) 
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```